# Removing reference dotted lines from Rechart graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm new with Rechart and I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the reference lines from it.

An image of the Chart with one of the lines rounded to mark what I mean:

[image: the chart]
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `<CartesianGrid />` component from the Chart to get rid from it.

You can also adjust it if you want, here are the [options](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/CartesianGrid).

See examples:

[with CartesianGrid](https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/xqjtetw0/)

[without CartesianGrid](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lw48zgs/)